# iTerm does not start up with Oh My Zsh theme

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

When starting iTerm2, my Oh My Zsh theme is not used:

[image]

Opening a second tab, however, does use the theme:

[image]

What did I configured wrong?

Comment: The same thing happens with iTerm2 v2.9.20160206/

Comment: Any help with this?